# python date format - '2016-08-02T18:43:58Z'

Tags: python, date, time, format

This is a pretty simple request. 
I'm looking to format the timestamp string - '2016-08-02T18:43:58Z' into a date format that I can compare on with Python.

I made it to here: 
   `(datetime.strptime(each_element['sentAt'], "%Y-%m-%d'T'%H:%M:%S'Z'"))`

but I'm still getting the error

`ValueError: time data '2016-08-02T18:43:58Z' does not match format "%Y-%m-%d'T'%H:%M:%S'Z'"`

Pretty sure the error is in the inclusion of the 't' and 'z' but I am stuck as to how to fix. Help?

Comment: That timestamp string is an ISO8601-EXT standard format. Surely there's a less hacky way to deal with this in python? Plus one though. (Your specific problem is the single quotation marks around the T and Z literals. Scrap 'em).

Comment: Why do you have `'` around `T` and `Z`?

Comment: Why did you quote the T, Z?